# changing the name of a downloaded file selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to change the file name of a file with selenium in python before/after it downloads? I do not want to use the os module. Thanks!
For example, what if my file was being download to `C:\foo\bar`, and its name is `foo.csv`, could i change it to `bar.csv`.

Comment: You can't do OS level operations using selenium, so you can't rename it after download. Additionally, you can't access save prompt while downloading, so you can't rename it before download. Consequently, it's not possible to do.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible with any Selenium library.

Use the normal Python method of renaming a file.